# How do I remove a CSS class from one anchor and assign it to another using jquery?

Tags: jquery, anchor, css

Here are my anchors,

```
<a ID="lnkbtn0" class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn1" class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn2" class="page-numbers" href="#">3</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn3" class="page-numbers" href="#">4</a>
```

And my click function i am adding a cssclass to show that it is the current anchor

```
$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('page-numbers current');
    });
```

What happens is when i click the next anchor the same class has been added to the current and the previous anchor... What can be done to remove the cssclass `page-numbers current` and assign cssclass `page-numbers` to the previous/all other anchors without changing the current one....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To avoid a costly run through the entire dom, do this:

```
$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('current').siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```

Comment: @Magnar wish i could mark this as answer.. But i have to wait because of SO Timing to mark an answer..

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Danrumb's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2545215/remove-cssclass-from-one-anchor-and-assign-to-another-in-jquery/2545229#2545229):

A simple solution would be to remove the `current` class for all (one) `a.page-numbers` and then add it to the clicked one:

```
$('a.page-numbers').click(function() {
    $('a.page-numbers').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: @jensgram ur latter one doesn't seem to work but the former one worked

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur Ok, I will revert my answer but, as you've already noticed, you're better off with @Magnar's solution :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
    $("a.page-numbers.current").removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
                $(this).addClass('current').siblings('a').removeClass('current');
    });
```

would also be a possibility, even if actually don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

The 'class' `page-numbers class` is actually 2 classes: `page-numbers` and `current`.

To add a class, you simply need

```
$(this).addClass('page-numbers');
```

To remove the `current` class, you would use:

```
$(this).removeClass('current');
```

See [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/css/) for more information.

Comment: @Dancrumb actually it is pagination when i click `page2` i have to remove class from `lnkbtn0` which would have had `page-numbers current`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
   $("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
                    $(this).addClass('current').prev('a').removeClass('current');
        });
```

This is assumes the previous element has current as a class.

Even better would be to do a two stage thing when you click:

1) loop through all the anchor tags and remove the current class from all of them
2) set the current element to have class current.

These means you can click on any of them and it should work

Answer (score 0):

```
<a ID="lnkbtn0" class="page-numbers" href="#">1</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn1" class="page-numbers" href="#">2</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn2" class="page-numbers" href="#">3</a>
<a ID="lnkbtn3" class="page-numbers" href="#">4</a>

$("a.page-numbers").click(function() {
    $('a.page-numbers.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
});
```

You don't need to keep adding `page-numbers`, as it's already been added.